# I need to update data from different google sheets to other sheet in real time. The data must be ordered in a table

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, importrange

I have to import all the data come from many google sheets to one google sheet in an specific order. I have to use the function "IMPORTRANGE", that function allows me to import the data to one google sheet. The problem is that a have no idea how to order the data in a table in real time. All the data come of many google forms, is for that reason that i don´t have the same data all the time.
Example:

I have 3 google sheets like this:

Google sheet 1:

```
Date   Name   Music   Design
1/1/1  Juan   2       0
2/1/1  Lucy   0       3
```

Google sheet 2:

```
Date   Name   Music   Design
1/1/1  Tom    2       0
4/1/1  Pedro  0       3
6/1/1  Carmen 1       4
```

Google sheet 3:

```
Date   Name   Music   Design
1/1/1  Mary   0       2
3/1/1  Justin 0       3
```

Each google sheet contains the data from their own google form 
So, i want to order the information in a google sheet in REAL TIME like this:

```
Date   Name   Music   Design
1/1/1  Juan   2       0
1/1/1  Tom    2       0
1/1/1  Mary   0       2
2/1/1  Lucy   0       3
3/1/1  Justin 0       3
4/1/1  Pedro  0       3
6/1/1  Carmen 1       4
```

The "date" means the date when data updated to the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1_fg2bHlXX6nPk_6FZSyy-CyzwCDSAmBP5XeQrOeKxmM", "sheet1!A2:D");
        IMPORTRANGE("1_fg2bHlXX6nPk_6FZSyy-CyzwCDSAmBP5XeQrOeKxmM", "sheet2!A2:D");
        IMPORTRANGE("1_fg2bHlXX6nPk_6FZSyy-CyzwCDSAmBP5XeQrOeKxmM", "sheet3!A2:D")}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0)
```

[image]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fg2bHlXX6nPk_6FZSyy-CyzwCDSAmBP5XeQrOeKxmM/edit#gid=1785967819)**

**note:** every **`IMPORTRANGE`** needs to be authorised separately, so first you need to import each spreadsheet like **`=IMPORTRANGE("1_fg2bHlXX6nPk_6FZSyy-CyzwCDSAmBP5XeQrOeKxmM", "sheet1!A2:D")`** in any cell and press that allow button. then you can delete it and construct your formula like in the picture

Answer (score -1):

Since you will need to authorise the link you might want to pull the data into one sheet before running a query on that, eg in case you need to sort out the separator convention. Assuming in each sheet `Date` is in A1, as a single formula:

```
=query({importrange(" k e y ","Sheet1!A1:D99");importrange(" k e y ","Sheet2!A1:D99");importrange(" k e y ","Sheet3!A1:D99")},"select * where Col1 is not NULL order by Col1")
```